# adding hours in current date

Tags: php

I am trying to build a simple system with login functionality, in which when a user login to a system, attendance of the user is recorded in database.

Further, in this i would like to add a functionality such as when user login to the system late(I mean, if s/he is supposed to login at 9 am an if s/he logsin after 9am, he needs to give the reason for being late).

I have done the attendace part, but i am stuck in the part of reason! i cant actually substract the date, and may be I am lacking the business logic too, can anyone guide me through this.

Comment: You need to add more info, like code, how you store the login time (9am), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
if ( time() > strtotime("07/17/2010 9:00AM") ) {
    // Do something
}
```

This will check if the current time is after 07/17/2010 9:00 AM.

Comment: The current date comes from `time()`. Both `time()` and `strtotime()` return a timestamp, then you can just compare these...

Comment: `strtotime()` uses a string as input - you will need current day, month and year - it will not be static... right? and to get these you'll need to get them from `date()` anyway...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now... If the user was required to login everyday at this time then he would need `date()`. I was assuming it would be a one off thing, or the required date/time would be set somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date`](http://php.net/date) function:

```
$h = (int)date("H");
$m = (int)date("i");
if($h>9 || $h==9 && $m>0) {
  // do what you have to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that is possible. A new table for attendance, then relate it to the user table using lets say attendance_id. After that, create new table to log the attendance name it table like attendance_log